# Gitlab - having both Docker-in-Docker and npm during build stage

Tags: docker, gitlab, linux, node.js

I'm building a nodejs app and need npm. On the other hand, I need Docker-in-Docker for building the image. I need both of them at the same time.

No image contains both npm and dind, there is a separate image for npm and another for dind.

In Gitlab, I tried this, but still get "docker: command not found":

```
default:
  image: node:14
  services:
    - docker:20-dind
```

How can I have both npm and docker-in-docker at the same time?

Comment: You can have a dockerfile with node and using dind container you can build this image.

Comment: Use a dockerfile to build the nodejs app. Then you only need 1 gitlab job which invokes `docker build`.